# Supercsv not skipping comments even with proper skip preferences

Tags: java, csv, file-io, comments, supercsv

I am trying to read CSV file and ignore the comments rows starting with "#". I believe I am setting the right preferences to ignore the comments but still, it is not getting ignored. Can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong.

```
                                                    if (file.exists()) {
                                                            InputStream inputStream =
                                                                    new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                                                            FileUtils
                                                                                    .readFileToByteArray(
                                                                                            file));
                                                            InputStreamReader
                                                                    inputStreamReaderAsync =
                                                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                                                            inputStream,
                                                                            "UTF-8");
                                                            beanReader =
                                                                    new CsvBeanReader(
                                                                            inputStreamReaderAsync,
                                                                            BulkDownloadServiceImpl.STANDARD_SKIP_COMMENTS);
                                                            // the header elements are used to map the values to the bean (names must match)
                                                            header =
                                                                    beanReader.getHeader(
                                                                            true);
                                                            inputStream.close();
                                                            isError = false;
                                                    }



    private static final CsvPreference STANDARD_SKIP_COMMENTS =
            new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE).skipComments(
                    new CommentStartsWith("#")).build();
```